# File conversion using ParaView

Tags: xml, json, vtk, collada, paraview

I have a problem converting some VTK medical data files: I have ParaView installed but am not able to convert these VTK files into the right format. How can I convert these files into XML, JSON, or COLLADA files using ParaView?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

VTK does have XML output writers.  When you go to Save File in ParaView, you can select them but they are dependent on the data set that you have.  They also have different file name extensions.  The list of serial XML writers for grids that derive from vtkDataSet are:

- vtkPolyData -- vtkXMLPolyDataWriter with extension .vtp
- vtkUnstructuredGrid -- vtkXMLUnstructuredGridWriter with extension .vtu
- vtkStructuredGrid -- vtkXMLStructuredGridWriter with extension .vts
- vtkRectilinearGrid -- vtkXMLRectilinearGridWriter with extension .vtr
- vtkImageData -- vtkXMLImageDataWriter with extension .vti